# Error when selecting row and column with Dataset[]

Tags: dataset

I read in my data using:

```
dat=Dataset[Import["dat.csv"]]
```

When I view the data it appears correct.
However, when I execute a command like

```
dat[1, "Colname1"]
```

I receive the error:

```
Message: Part Colname 1 is not applicable to expressions of the form {_String, _, _String, \"country" | "NA" | "us", _, _, _String, _String, _, _String, _String, \_String, _String, _, _, 

Tag: Dataset
```

I'm not sure why this is happening, unfortunately I can't give a reproducible example with the data.

Comment: `Dataset` querying of that form requires you to convert the table imported by `Import` into a list of `Association`s. That's pretty easy to do with something like `Map[Association@Thread[First[#]->Rest[#]]&, Import["dat.csv"]]`

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out soon after asking.